# AdMob at publishing

Tags: android, admob, publish

it´s a simple question. After having some problems with the implementation of the admob for an android app, finally it works.

I am programming in Android 2.2 (8) and I read that if I don´t want to have problems with the console etc, I have to change the target in properties (not in the manifest) to target13, and then simulate with the API 13 (a tablet view). OK, with this steps, the log cat works well and the console don´t give me a typical message saying "You must adActivity AndroidManifest..."

Now I have finish "my app". And my question is, I have to change again the target from 13 to 8 in eclipse, before publishing my app??? Or the project.properties file, doesn´t matter?

And finally, to get the ID of the publish from adMob first I have to had my app upload? 
If it is yes the basic steps could be this ones? First upload the app- then get the id of the publish from adMOb- write the id on the eclipse- and finally refresh my app again on the market??

Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build your admob enabled app ready for market publishing, leave the target=13 in project.properties, only modify the minSDKVersion property in your AndroidManifest.xml point to your targeting version (8 in your case).

You can get Admob publishID and use it into your application code before upload/publish app in android market, to get a publishID, sign in and login in your admob account, click Sites & Apps -> Add Site/App, choose create a Android App, in the setup menu, you will be ask to enter the application market URL, this does not need to be existed at this point. following Eg: market://details?id=**packagename** to make one. Admob will generate the publishID for you to use.

You can actually test admob at this stage now, install your admob enabled application on you phone, play with it (click the ads several times), you will start earning revenue in your admob account.

hope that help.

Comment: Just one note about clicking your own ads, this is not recommended and is considered abuse, and may result in freezing of your AdMob account.  I recommend [enabling test mode](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html#adrequest) during development, and then you don't have to worry about clicking your own ads.

Comment: @Eric Leichtenschlag, Thanks for your note. Yes it is, More details about fraud click at [here](http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/click-fraud)

Comment: thank you... I haven´t upload the app yet ( I hope to do at the end of the weekend). I follow your steps and I add in the uRL: market://details?id=<car.machine>, then I take the publish ID and I set in the 2 xml in the code--> ads:adUnitId="axxxxxxxxxxx". And when I run the app works perfect! But one cuestion when I upload the app I don´t have tu change the URL at admob?

Comment: market URL has a fixed pattern, for example, if package in your AndroodManifest.xml is com.rovio.angrybirds, just replace <car.machine> with com.rovio.angrybirds, this will be the final URL when upload and publish your app in android market. better to set it correct at first place, though it doesn't need to be as your can always change it later. go to the [market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds) and check out some app's URL, You should get a clear idea how app's market URL is generated.

Comment: Just a note, as a consequence of using api-13 or higher eclpise will start using the corresponding new jar file for android api calls. Eclipse auto complete will show you all methods, be sure not to use only methods which are available in your minSDK version if you don't your app will crash when running on platforms where u don't have given api